# jQuery fadeToggle() fades out, but not in

Tags: jquery, html, css

The two divs are fading out properly but will not fade back in.

Here's some code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".slideBar").mouseover(function(){
      $(this).fadeToggle();
    });
  });
</script>
```

As for the CSS:

```
.slideHeader{
  vertical-align: right;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 6%;
}

.slideBar{
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% / 20);
  background-color: rgb(64, 64, 64, .5);
  position: absolute;
}

#sbLeft{
  left: 0;
}

#sbRight{
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: can you show your html code ?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should used `mouseleave`, or `mouseout` event  also .
When you move the mouse pointer in `.slidebar` element the mouseover event execute and nothings happen when you leaving the mouse pointer.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".slideBar").mouseover(function(){
      $(this).fadeToggle();
    });

    $(".slideBar").mouseleave(function(){
      $(this).fadeToggle();
    });
  });
```

Comment: After doing this, when my mouse is hovering over the div, it will pulse. fading in and out without any movement of the mouse ... :/

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/), `fadeToggle()`:

> Display or hide the matched elements by animating their opacity.

So once the element has faded out, the `display` is set to `none`. Therefore, you just can't have an event from that element to toggle it back in.

Your only option is to use an event on another displayed element...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var bar = $(".slideBar");
  var btn = $("#displayBtn");
  
  bar.mouseover(function(){
    $(this).fadeToggle();
    
    // Show a button.
    btn.fadeToggle();
  });
  
  btn.click(function(){
    $(this).fadeToggle();
    
    // Show the bar.
    bar.fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.slideHeader{
  vertical-align: right;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 6%;
}

.slideBar{
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% / 20);
  background-color: rgb(64, 64, 64, .5);
  position: absolute;
}

#sbLeft{
  left: 0;
}

#sbRight{
  right: 0;
}

#displayBtn{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="slideBar"></div>
<button id="displayBtn">Bring it back!</button>
```